# Conditionally Include Dependency package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a dependency that is only needed for Mac OS in an npm project and was wondering if there is some way to conditionally include this dependency only when the compatible platform is the one running `npm install`.

I'm willing to write the logic for this.  In the below case `grunt-appdmg` is causing the npm install process to error out (for fairly obvious reasons) with:

```
'/dev/cuttle/node_modules/grunt-appdmg/node_modules/appdmg/node_modules/ds-store/node_modules/macos-alias/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/volume/src/volume.o
../src/volume.cc:9:2: error: #error This platform is not implemented yet
 #error This platform is not implemented yet
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Cuttle",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/oakmac/cuttle",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/oakmac/cuttle.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "0.16.3",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "winston": "0.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "0.11.4",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.6.1",
    "grunt-curl": "2.0.3",
    "grunt-download-atom-shell": "0.10.0",
    "grunt-appdmg": "0.2.0",
    "winresourcer": "0.9.0",
    "moment": "2.9.0",
    "shelljs": "0.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use an optional dependency.

Like this in your package.json:

```
"optionalDependencies":{
  "grunt-appdmg":"0.2.0"
}
```

More info on [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#optionaldependencies)

`npm install` will then just skip it if it fails.

Comment: Is there a way to also include dependencies, conditioned on OS or system variables?

Comment: To my knowledge, it is not possible.

Comment: If you have control over the call to `npm install` (like during a build script), you can pass the `--no-optional` flag to skip installing the optional dependencies outright, without even trying.  That will at least keep the optional packages out of your CI build.

Answer (score 6):

Let me introduce [handpick](https://github.com/henryruhs/handpick) that lets you target and filter multiple dependencies. I wrote this to speed up CI stages that just need a fragment of the devDependencies but there are eventually more usecases. This project is quite experimental - please leave some feedback.

### Installation

Install on your system:

```
npm install handpick --global
```

### Usage

Run the command:

```
handpick [options]

-V, --version
-T, --target
-F, --filter
-M, --manager
-P, --path
-h, --help
```

### Examples

Define unofficial dependencies inside `package.json` file:

```json
{
    "lintDependencies":
    {
        "eslint": "6.8.0"
    },
    "testDependencies":
    {
        "mocha": "7.1.1"
    }
}
```

Install the `lintDependencies`:

```
handpick --target=lintDependencies
```

Install the `devDependencies` and `lintDependencies` via YARN:

```
handpick --target=devDependencies --target=lintDependencies --manager=yarn
```

Install the `devDependencies` without `testDependencies`:

```
handpick --target=devDependencies --filter=testDependencies
```

Install the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` within path:

```
handpick --path=../shared
```

Comment: @MukeshKumarGupta Can you specify your question? You can create "prodDependencies" if they don't match the "dependencies" entry. Or you just use --filter=devDependencies to get rid of things you don't need in prod.

Comment: Basically, We have an angular repo that gets deployed in the cloud and the same repo used to generate the msi. In MSI We build node modules and copy it in our MSI. In the cloud, we don't install 2 packages in cloud we take those dependencies based on script tag, and MSI we install that item. 
I have scene your lib solve the problem but my problem is maintenance of repo in future. How can I write the command with the npm script? 

If possible we can go over call over zoom or meet ?