# npm install regardless OS and architecture

Tags: node.js, npm, cross-platform, npm-install

I have a node.js script that run in Linux and Windows platform. I use package `node-windows` for communicate with windows and use `node-linux` for Linux. Now when I want to run in linux node error me:

> Error: Cannot find module 'node-windows'

and when wanna to install `node-windows` in Linux error me:

```
npm ERR! node v8.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v5.6.0
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: 
node-windows@1.1.3
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/william/app/mcard-api/npm-debug.log
```

Is there any way to `npm install` regardless package OS and architecture dependency?
If No, Is there any way to `require` package by platform in source code?

Comment: I think this may answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710232/conditionally-include-dependency-package-json

Comment: thanks, but isn't my answer