# How to stop node from loading local packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an issue where when running a package with node it is running code from an unrelated package in an adjacent directory. My directory structure is as follows:

- **Root**

  - **Package**

    - index.js
    - package.json
  - **Directory**

    - **Shared**

      - index.js
      - package.json
    - **Service**

      - index.js
      - package.json

**Root**: Contains a git repo for the entire project. 
**Package**: The package I am attempting to run. 
*index.js*

```
console.log("Hello world!")
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node ./index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Directory**: A directory containing serverless service packages. 
**Shared**: A package that is shared with the serverless services through a symlink (`npm link`). Overwrites `console.log` with a custom function.
**Service**: A serverless service that accesses **Shared**.

Running `node index.js` in the **Package** directory results in the custom `console.log` function being used from the **Shared** directory. Renaming *index.js* to *index.js.ori* in **Shared** results in the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module '**Root**\**Directory**\**Service**\node_modules\**Shared**\index.js'.
> Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
> at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:297:19)
> at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:18)
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:780:27)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:686:27)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
> at Object. (F:\Mosaic\Git\API\documentation\index.js:1:24)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32) {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> path: '**Root**\**Directory**\**Service**\node_modules\**Shared**\package.json',
> requestPath: '../**Directory**/**Service**/node_modules/**Shared**'
> }

The runtime environment is a Windows 10 PC. Any assistance with preventing node from loading the unrelated code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please read this discussion: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15755.  And consider changing your project structure ;)

Comment: From my understanding that thread is an alternative for the Shared symlink? My concern is why the Package project is invoking anything from Service / Shared when no file references or imports them.

Comment: No, my understanding from the thread is 1) "NODE_PATH is deprecated and does not work w/ ESM loader", and 2) "Right now the rule is 'look in node_modules' and every developer knows that".  My suggestion is to reorganize your project so that all "3rd party" packages your project's local node_modules and all local modules are are *unambiguously* declared. No "conflicts", no implicit "search order".  See also [npm optionalDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#optionaldependencies): https://stackoverflow.com/a/28710549/421195

Comment: The issue has been resolved. It embarrassingly was caused by an import that VSCode had done automatically without me noticing. Thanks for your help regardless!